# In Debian 11 docker container, I cannot type lowercase S when I switch to bash from zsh

Tags: bash, debian, python, inputrc, stty

When I connect to my **Docker container** with **Debian 11** via **ssh**, I have it set up such that **zsh** is the main shell. When I switch to **bash** (by typing `bash`) I lose the ability to type the lowercase letter `s` (no such problem with any other letter, lower or uppercase, even UTF-8 and other, non-latin alphabets, work).

It is the same if I connect via `docker attach CONTAINER_NAME` (because then, **bash** is the default shell, not **zsh**). This problem persists across various terminal applications and regardless of whether I connect as `root` or another user.

The locales are all configured as `en_US.UTF-8`

The issue appears to be in `stty` or `.inputrc`, I suspect, and a tried variations of settings of each, yet no matter what I try, nothing seems to make any difference (I double check and reboot the container every time).

Furthermore, it appears that upon loading a **Python 3.11** console which is started by one of the python cli-apps run from under zsh (not bash!), I also cannot type the lowercase letter `s` there. More interestingly, while in bash I can at least paste it, Python console simply refuses to even accept it pasted, basically stripping  all letters `s`.

Below are my .inputrc settings:

```
"\e[A": history-search-backward
"\e[B": history-search-forward
set show-all-if-ambiguous on
set completion-ignore-case on

# Settings ensuring certain typed ASCII charachters are printing
set output-meta on
set input-meta on
set convert-meta off
```

FIY: commenting them all out didn't help, as well as setting the same settings in `/etc/inputrc`. And here's the current stty settings (set to `stty sane`, but I tried various different kinds):

```
$ stty --all
speed 38400 baud; rows 43; columns 170; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>; eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W;
lnext = ^V; discard = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd -cmspar cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl -ixon -ixoff -iuclc -ixany imaxbel -iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt echoctl echoke -flusho -extproc
```

And, just in case the output of `locale` command (ran when in bash):

```
$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

The the contents of the global `/etc/inputrc` is this:

```
$ cat /etc/inputrc 
# /etc/inputrc - global inputrc for libreadline
# See readline(3readline) and `info rluserman' for more information.

# Be 8 bit clean.
set input-meta on
set output-meta on

# To allow the use of 8bit-characters like the german umlauts, uncomment
# the line below. However this makes the meta key not work as a meta key,
# which is annoying to those which don't need to type in 8-bit characters.

set convert-meta off

# try to enable the application keypad when it is called.  Some systems
# need this to enable the arrow keys.
set enable-keypad on

# see /usr/share/doc/bash/inputrc.arrows for other codes of arrow keys

# do not bell on tab-completion
set bell-style none
# set bell-style visible

# some defaults / modifications for the emacs mode
$if mode=emacs

# allow the use of the Home/End keys
"\e[1~": beginning-of-line
"\e[4~": end-of-line

# allow the use of the Delete/Insert keys
"\e[3~": delete-char
"\e[2~": quoted-insert

# mappings for "page up" and "page down" to step to the beginning/end
# of the history
# "\e[5~": beginning-of-history
# "\e[6~": end-of-history

# alternate mappings for "page up" and "page down" to search the history
# "\e[5~": history-search-backward
# "\e[6~": history-search-forward

# mappings for Ctrl-left-arrow and Ctrl-right-arrow for word moving
"\e[1;5C": forward-word
"\e[1;5D": backward-word
"\e[5C": forward-word
"\e[5D": backward-word
"\e\e[C": forward-word
"\e\e[D": backward-word

#$if term=rxvt
#"\e[7~": beginning-of-line
#"\e[8~": end-of-line
#"\eOc": forward-word
#"\eOd": backward-word
#$endif

# for non RH/Debian xterm, can't hurt for RH/Debian xterm
# "\eOH": beginning-of-line
# "\eOF": end-of-line

# for freebsd console
# "\e[H": beginning-of-line
# "\e[F": end-of-line

$endif
```

I think I never cared much about it until I had to work with the Python console, and I believe this is somehow connected.

Can anyone advise?

**UPDATE:** while `bind '"s": self-insert'` helped with the bash itself, the python console still refuses to type or accept lower case letter `s`, regardless of whether it's being launched from zsh or from bash  after running the suggested command. Also, the suggested `bind` command prints quite a few similar warnings when added to .bashrc, the  warnings are this:

```
bind: warning: line editing not enabled
```

I mitigated this by redirecting STDERR to /dev/null, but the root cause of the problem seems to be unsolved.

Comment: In the affected bash, what is the output of `bind -p | grep '"s":'`?

Comment: This command outputs nothing. Without grep, the piece of output in the region where the letter `s` must be is absent. It goes `r` to `t`, skipping `s`.

Comment: Does `bind '"s": self-insert'` help?

Comment: Yes, it helped immediately. Can you maybe post an answer with the explanation. I still don't understand what's the reason for such behavior.

Comment: What is the content of `/etc/inputrc`? Please [edit] the question and add information there (not in comments).

Comment: Edited the question, added the info you requested.

Comment: What if you add `"s": self-insert` to your `~/.inputrc`?